# Why Functor restricts the definition of map?

Tags: haskell, functor

I was listening at the LambdaConf 2015 talk by Kris Nuttycombe titled *Parametricity The Essence of Information Hiding*. At [12:20](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6de5KWFY6M&t=738s), the speaker talks about why the definition of this function isn't `map`, even though it shares the same type signature:

> ```
> asdf :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
> ```
>
> - Every value in the output is obtained by applying the
>   function provided to a member of the input.
> - **BUT** *List* gives the implementer too much information,
>   and thecaller too little.
>
>   ```
>   asdf :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
>   asdf f [] = []
>   asdf f (x : _) = [f x]
>   ```

Of course, the type signature is the same as `map`; however, the result is a singleton list with `f` applied to the head.

The speaker says that we should place a `Functor` restriction. From that point, I couldn't understand why is that. Could someone give me any pointers?

Comment: Frankly the talk is a bit chaotic, but it seems the speaker wants to say that *in the ideal world where we can enforce type class laws in the language*, the `Functor`'s `fmap` *could have* been constrained to behave as a real true honest map, in a way that `asdf` can't.

Comment: Or perhaps he wanted to say that `asdf :: Functor f => (a->b) -> f a -> f b` can only be defined equivalently to `asdf = fmap` (modulo `undefined`). *If* we trust that `fmap` is implemented correctly (we cannot enforce it in the language, see above, we just assume that well-established libraries like Prelude are implemented correctly), then we can trust `asdf` to behave correctly too (or go to the undefined land, which any function in Haskell can, so we can't do much about it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speaker is arguing in favor of types. He wants to show the audience that types can under certain circumstances be used to limit possible implementations. When he gets at

```
asdf :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

he explains that this would allow more than one implmentation but switching to a `Functor` constraint would help with that.

```
asdf :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

He also seems to split his talk into a first part where he ignores the finer points to get his main message across and a second part where he goes into some of the finer points. For what is worth I share your confusion of the speaker's argument in the first part and I would consider it as fast and loose reasoning. I think you should not dig too deep as well.

On a final note, you probably will enjoy Edward Kmett's *[The free theorem for fmap](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/edwardk/snippets/fmap)* which also lists the free theorem for `fmap` and gives a link to Philip Wadler's [*Theorems for Free!*](https://home.ttic.edu/%7Edreyer/course/papers/wadler.pdf).